# Pwm motor control of peristaltic pump

Tags: motor, motor-controller

Hi this is my first time posting to this forum.  I am controlling a peristaltic pump with a pwm signal that is low pass filtered and fed into a darlington driver. When I measure the input wave form to the darlington it is essentially a dc signal.  The pump side is slightly noisy but still is an almost perfect dc signal. My problem is that I cant get good torque out of the motor.  If I use a nice linear power supply I can get the motor to start at 1/3 of the voltage it will start at with my motor controller.  How can I get excellent starting torque.

Comment: "*How can I get excellent starting torque.*", is this your question?

Comment: Dont use a Darlington that drops 2V on startup. Use a FET rated for 10x the current in order to get low Ron. Starting current is always >5x max rated current. Dont they teach this in school?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment I just tested a high power mosfet.  I was unable to get it to start even at 80% duty cycle.  With a 1000uf capacitor across the motor I was able to get it to run down to 60% duty cycle then it stalled.  I found that I could still not get it to start at low speeds.

Comment: For good torque you **don't** want a low DC value. Remove the low pass filter and use the unfiltered PWM output.

Comment: I initially had the circuit configured with just pwm signal directly to the Darlington.  I had the same issue with starting torque I don't think that using the low pass filter helped but because my linear power supply could drive it at such low speeds I thought I would try using a dc voltage to control it.  I also observed that my current consumption was about double with the Darlington driver compared to the linear power supply,

Comment: Use a MOSFET, and put it on the low side, between the negative and ground.

Comment: Ok thanks every one I'm an idiot I wasn't driving the gate of my mosfet with enough voltage thats why I seemed like it wasn't working.  I appreciate all the help and I should definitely use a mosfet instead of a Darlington driver.

Answer (score 0):

What you presumably have (you should have put this in your question):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDyQLn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What you should be doing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnh81p.png)</sup>

Comment: You are 100% correct.  The performance has improved dramatically.  I am still not getting it to start at as low speed as I can with my power supply but it is much improved.

Comment: if you chose the correct FET, it should be identical