# Power control of centrifugal pump via PWM or voltage

Tags: voltage, pwm, fluid-pump

I would like to change the flux rate of a centrifugal pump like these ones here:

- [Wilo centrifugal pump](https://wilo.com/at/de/Katalog/en/products-expertise/wilo-jet-wj)
- [Homa centrifugal pump](https://www.homa-pumpen.de/gebaeudetechnik/produkt/universalpumpen-gpe60-gpe71-gpe105-50-hz)

I can only think of [PWM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358029/pwm-motor-control-of-peristaltic-pump) or voltage control from 0-230V or using trial and error. How would you try to adjust the flux rate of such a pump?

Comment: If you make does loop system, some sensor should be used. And best way to control turns off asynchronous motor is to change frequency. Some controller are exist.

Comment: The Wilo pump uses a 3-phase motor. Are you intending to use a 3-phase power supply? These are not small toy pumps, they are real industrial equipment and off-the-shelf solutions to this problem (namely Variable Frequency Drives) are used in factories everywhere.